# What would happen if a human was exposed to the red sun of Krypton?

Tags: dc, superman, krypton

In most incarnations of *Superman*, Kryptonians gain their superpowers from exposure to a *yellow sun* (primarily our own), and do not receive such benefits near their own, red sun-dominated Krypton.

Is it ever explored what the result would be if an Earth human were to travel to Krypton and be exposed to its red sun?

- Would the human gain Superman-like superpowers? (e.g. superpowers derive from being exposed to a *different* sun)
- Would the human become weaker? (e.g. red suns weaken *everybody* from a certain baseline species level, yellow suns likewise grant them advantages over a baseline....)

I know that generally, Krypton is destroyed and the practicality of human travel to Krypton does not come up. I'm interested in if this was *ever* explored at any point, in any continuity, perhaps using time travel, wormholes, or whatever.